# Using SignalR on an asp.net Core app that targets the full .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an existing `ASP.net Core` app that targets the full `4.6.1 .NET Framework` instead of the `.NETCore framework`.

I need to know: is there ANY way to use `SignalR` on such an app? Reading around the net I found some people claimning to have fount workarounds, but I cannot find any details on exactly HOW to do it.

Any info on this subject is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after a lot of searching I found a sample project that implements this. You can find it here:

https://github.com/jkells/signalr2-netcore-websockets-sample

I implemented their same solution on my project and it works! Read the info on the github Readme carefully: you have to add the repository they mention to your nuget sources in visual studio or packages won't restore correctly.