# SignalR 2 Websockets with ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-2

I have an ASP.NET Core application, running on .NET Framework 4.6.2. I managed to run SignalR 2 by using owin-middleware. 
The issue is that it uses server events, instead of websockets. Is there any setup that can be done, in order to use websockets?
[image]

In `Startup.cs` I am calling both 
`app.UseWebSockets()`;
`app.UseSignalR2()` // custom extension method maps signalR to appbuilder

If specifying only webSockets transport, it doesn't have any errors, but it does not connect.

I have used a similar setup using a ASP.NET MVC project, and it worked as expected, this only reproduces when using ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework.

I found some similar posts, but I was not able to run it using websockets:
[Using SignalR on an asp.net Core app that targets the full .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618771/using-signalr-on-an-asp-net-core-app-that-targets-the-full-net-framework)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's missing the UseWebSockets method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
        app.UseWebSockets();
}
```

Comment: Do you use IIS as reverse proxy? If yes you also need to activate websockets on it. Also check for http/https mismatches.

Comment: I am using IIS, but since it is working for ASP.NET MVC application, I assume that IIS is not the issue.

Comment: Do you have the WebSocket protocol enabled for IIS? It's under Windows Features -> IIS -> WWW Services -> App Dev Features.

Comment: Yes, I enabled this. Still, no change.